# How do I make my images in my div change opacity on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make each picture change opacity on hover, but I can't make it work.

When I'm using: img:hover {opacity: 0.4;} only the 6th picture changes opacity.
I've also tried using "#prototype img[src="xxx"]:hover" trying to target every picture individually, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Right now I'm pretty much stuck. How do I make this work? I'm still new to all this, so every little bit of help is appreciated.

Here's the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/jzaeehhq/

HTML:

```
<div id="prototype" onclick="expand();">
    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/MEbxzVL.png" alt="menu1">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/TMZ4hXu.png" alt="menu2">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/VeJ6BR2.png" alt="menu3">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/aIYy0qr.png" alt="menu4">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/QO0Z8TE.png" alt="menu5">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uGopItw.png" alt="menu6">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#prototype  { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 47.5%;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: All of your images are the same size, and overlayed exactly ontop of each other. So you won't be able to get the individual segments changing opacity as you hover over them. Technically, you're only hovering over the last image, because this is the most top-wards image on the stack.

Comment: @Lee Ah, that makes absolute sense. Thank you. So if I wanted this to work I would have to crop out every picture?

Comment: Well I'm not actually sure to be honest. It's quite tricky. You could look into maybe SVG shapes, and then applying the opacity to those, as I'm not sure but I think they will hover when your cursor actually touches the boundaries of the shape, and not a square that fits around it.

Comment: Yes, you need crop all images and set: `position: absolute` and use **css transform: rotate** ;) this link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your images all are 300X300px, so they are overlapping each other:

[image: overlap]

But you should reduce size of all iamges and place them without overlapping:

[image: no overlap]

Hope you get the idea :)

Comment: Great example! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   div img:hover {
 opacity:0.1;
}
```

I suggest you use class-tags though let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for answering! Unfortunately this again only makes nr. 6 change opacity. =(

Comment: i think thats because you have all images on the same position

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
:hover #prototype {
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

Note how the line starts with `:hover` -- no selector (ie class or id or tag) was used before it.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jzaeehhq/2/

Comment: You could ID every img and put that name instead of #prototype, in rder to make it count for every image.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee said, you only hover last image.

Try this with map element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map.